# Method overloading using params keyword

Tags: c#, parameters

```
class D
{
    public void foo(int z, int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("foo with two parameters");
    }
    public void foo(params int[] z)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("foo with two params parameter");
    }
}
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {       
        D obj = new D();
        obj.foo(10,20);
    }
}
```

When I run this code, the method `foo(int x, int y)` is executed instead of `foo(params int[] z)`. Why is this?

Comment: Because you have an overload that matches _exactly_. Read: [`7.4.2` Overload resolution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Becuase closest always match so called `public void foo(int z, int x)`

Comment: Also from Eric Lippert: [Closer is better](http://ericlippert.com/2013/12/23/closer-is-better/)

Answer (score 5):

The C# compiler will always try to select the metod that matches the arguments most closely. In your case the `foo(int, int)` overload matches your input arguments exactly, while the `foo(params int)` overload is a weaker match.

Here is a nice overview of method overloading in C# if you are interested: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Because in your case there is an overload that match exactly.