# Constructor selection for multiple optional parameters of the same type

Tags: c#, .net, compilation

In the code below, `CreateNode` calls the first constructor, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28561065/method-overloading-using-params-keyword) (thanks for the link).

```
public class Node
{
    public Node(Node parent = null, params Node[] children) { }
    public Node(params Node[] children) { }
    public Node CreateNode() => new Node(new Node(), new Node()); }
}
```

What is the best way to deal with this whilst retaining the cross purpose constructor functionality (it allows for more expressive composition of code eg XElement).

I was thinking maybe temporarily wrap or cast the `parent`, but that obviously introduces more boilerplate. Not sure if I could somehow leverage the `ValueTuple<>` syntax to get what i want? Or implicit and explicit operators?!

***EDIT***

I wanted to create the nodes in a similar fashion to XElement, etc. eg

```
new Node(new Node(new Node())
```

however there were cases where I had already created a parent and wanted to pass that into the constructor of its child nodes eg

```
Node parent = new Node();
new Node(parent, new Node(), new Node());
```

Obviously the compiler has to chose one, and so I guess I was really asking how to force it to choose the other, so it knows the first argument should be treated as the parent.

Comment: So you want to call the second one instead?

Comment: Yes, I would like to be able to select one or the other using the minimal amount of syntactic sugar possible! This is more of a question of enabling a succinct style of coding than performance, etc, I'm wondering how best it would be done :0)

Comment: Not related to your question, but why is the `parent` parameter optional? Isn't calling the first overload and passing `null` to `parent` the same as calling the second overload? You are creating a node without a parent in both cases, right?

Comment: I might create a node with a parent, a node with a parent and children, or a node with just with children. These two constructors cover all bases. I'm an awkward customer, sorry :-D

Comment: I still don't see why `parent` has to be optional? Now you've got two ways of creating a node without a parent... `new Node(new [] { new Node() })` (second constructor) and `new Node(null, new Node())` (first constructor)

Comment: IMO, if you want clear code, you shouldn't be using parameter arrays in the first place. They just make it very hard to tell what you are creating. Just use regular arrays, and always do `new[] { ... }`. This way it is crystal clear which are the children, and which are the parents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are passing the parameter array in its "expanded form", which causes this rule to apply, making both methods an [applicable function member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#applicable-function-member).

> If a function member that includes a parameter array is not applicable
> in its normal form, the function member may instead be applicable in
> its expanded form:
>
> - The expanded form is constructed by replacing the parameter array in the function member declaration with zero or more value parameters of
>   the element type of the parameter array such that the number of
>   arguments in the argument list A matches the total number of
>   parameters. [...]

And then the rules in [better function member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#better-function-member) decide that the first one is a better function member. Specifically, this one:

> Otherwise, if `Mp` has more declared parameters than `Mq`, then `Mp` is better than `Mq`. This can occur if both methods have params arrays and are applicable only in their expanded forms.

So to solve this problem, just pass your parameter in its "normal form", i.e. as an array. It's not that much more keystrokes if you use an implicitly typed array.

```
new Node(new[] { new Node(), new Node() })
```

This way, only one overload is an applicable function member.

Comment: Yes, I like this option, as you say, only a couple of extra keystrokes! Can that work the other way round? eg wrap the parent in an array (bear with me!) instead of the children, since that is the less common scenario (still chasing those last few keystrokes!!). Cheers.

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 You can do `new Node(someParent, new[] { children1, children2  })` too, but you still have to wrap the children in an array. How about a static method like `Node.WithChildren`?

Comment: Sorry I'm being dumb, both constructors together as arrays would mean i always have to declare as `new[]` so please ignore that comment, sorry!

Comment: `Node.WithChildren` also a nice option. Thanks very much for your help. GME ;0)